# How can I extract the individual string values from a multimap?

Tags: java, guava

My map is declared as:

```
 ListMultimap<String, String> myMutlimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

I've been able to print just the keys:

```
TEN   
TT2
TP1
TP2
TRK
TAL
COM
COM
COM
TCO
TPA
TYE
```

or the values or the keys and values:

```
TEN=children's story
TT2=black star
TP1=black star
TP2=5/13
TRK=This old album
COM=This album is good
COM=This album is great
COM=This album is awesome
TCO=hip-hop
TPA=1/2
TYE=2002
```

But, when I try to list the value of the "COM" key I get:

```
[This album is good, This album is great, This album is awesome ]
```

How can I get the individual values of the "COM" key without resorting to string splitting the "=" sign away? I think if I could get the key and value on the same line, it would also make it easy to assign them to variables.

```
TEN children's story
TT2 black star
TP1 black star
TP2 5/13                                            
COM This album is good
COM This album is great
COM This album is awesome
or    
COM This album is good
    This album is great
    This album is awesome
```

I know that are ways I can use these keys and values as variables already but, I am looking for a clean and succinct way to do this - that also prints nicely.

Edit: 
As requested here are some methods I've tried:

```
for (Object key : myMutlimap.keys()) {
        System.out.println(key);

    }

    for (Object value : myMutlimap.values()) {
        System.out.println(value);

    }

    for (Object value : myMutlimap.entries()) {
        System.out.println(value.toString());
    }

    for (String value : myMutlimap.keySet()) {
        System.err.println(value);
        System.out.println(myMutlimap.get("COM"));
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with just using `get()`? (Or specifically, using `get()` and then iterating however you want through the collection)

Comment: Could you give me some instruction on using this method to get the output I'm looking for?

Comment: If the existing answer is not enough, you should post what you have _actually_ tried so far, _with the code_. Because what I infer from the bits of information you've given is that you're trying to parse the output of `toString()` to get the content of the `Multimap`, when you should simply be using the [API](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Comment: I think it's obvious that I am having trouble wrapping my head around the API. I have stated the output I desire and, have added a few mthods I have tried. Can you be of any assistance? I would really like to learn how to get the output I'm trying to get.

Comment: @frank-pavageau - for clarity - When I print the values of "COM", the strings are printed in a bunch as if they are one continuous string.

Comment: That's just the String representation of the collection of values associated to the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the type parameters of the `Multimap` (or even the return type of the methods, for that matter), so of course `Object` won't get you far.

With an instance of `Multimap<String, String>`, you have the following (interesting) methods available:

- `Map<String, Collection<String>> asMap()` to get the `Map` view, where each key has a collection of values
- `Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries()` to get the individual entries, i.e. each (key, value) pair
- `Collection<String> get(String key)` to get all the values for a given key
- `Multiset<String> keys()` to get all the keys without duplicates **and** be able to know how many values are associated to each of them
- `Set<String> keySet()` to get the `Set` of keys, again without duplicates
- `Collection<String> values()` to get the collection of all values present in the `Multimap`, without knowing which key they are associated to

Knowing that, if you want to print the values for a given key, you just have to do this:

```
for (String value : myMultimap.get("COM")) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

If you want to do the same for all available keys, you have several options:

1. Iterate on the keys and lookup their values:

   ```
   for (String key : myMultimap.keySet()) {
       for (String value : myMultimap.get(key)) {
           System.out.println(key + " " + value);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Iterate on the entries of the `Multimap` (the (key, value) pairs):

   ```
   for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMultimap.entries()) {
       String key = entry.getKey(), value = entry.getValue();
       System.out.print(key + " " + value);
   }
   ```
3. Iterate on the entries of the `Map` view:

   ```
   for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry :
                myMultimap.asMap().entrySet()) {
       String key = entry.getKey();
       Collection<String> values = entry.getValue();
       for (String value : values) {
           System.out.println(key + " " + value);
       }
   }
   ```

   This method has the advantage of giving you access to the collection of values for each key (so you have a nice collection with all its available methods, like `size()`, or that could can manipulate further), like in option 1, **but** without the need of an extra lookup in the `Multimap` for each key.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I really appreciate the effort you made to clear that up for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `get()` and iterate over the list that it returns to get the values individually.

```
List<String> values = myMutlimap.get("COM");
for (String s: values) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```